# How can I create the required layout of nested collapsible containers using Twitter Bootstrap (with panels, accordions etc.)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I would like to create the layout as shown in the following picture. I am currently using Twitter Bootstrap's layout and controls to create a web application.

[image: Desired layout]

There are outer containers below one another and each outer one has containers within them. I would like all containers to be collapsible i.e. I would like to minimize each one, including the outer containers. All containers should be shown on screen on load.

When all inner containers are minimized / collapsed, the parent outer container should then collapse as well. I am also open to suggestions on the location of the minimized parent containers (to the left, top or bottom).

I am not sure how to create this layout (either with the accordion control or with panels or any other suggestion anyone may have) and would like to know if anyone has a suitable suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

***Some suggestions and thoughts. I hope it's guidance of somewhat!***

#### Functionality

You might be able to use the built-in js to manage this, but not too sure about it. However, I believe the collapsability is executed with js but that it regulates css-code such as [`display` and `visibility`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp). I also believe that these collapsable scripts are triggered by the js's in the end of the document, and it only does so depending on the screen resolution. So I don't know for sure how much of the scripts you could actually use for this type of active choice of collapsabilty. I'd look into coding it myself if I were you.

#### Type of conent?

What kind of content do you want in your div's? (Title A.1 - Title C.3). For better user experience I'd suggest a layout something like the picture I included. Especially if the user wants to view it from a mobile device, but not exclusively. Text in a vertical angle is basically just pain for the neck. But if you insist on that approach I'd suggest Icons.

*A suggestion for the layout regarding usability and user experience.*
[image: Approach suitable for mobile devices]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will have a look into your suggestions and let you know how it goes!